# Convert String to Bytes in Java

Tags: java, pack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

I got an MD5 String

```
de70d4de8c47385536c8e08348032c3b
```

and I need it as the Byte Values

```
DE 70 D4 DE 8C 47 38 55 36 C8 E0 83 48 03 2C 3B
```

This should be similar to Perls `pack("H32);` function.

Comment: So you want to transform the string from this: `de70d4de8c47385536c8e08348032c3b` to this: `DE 70 D4 DE 8C 47 38 55 36 C8 E0 83 48 03 2C 3B`?

Comment: Nearly, I don't want this to be seen as the String in a textfile, but as the bytes.

Comment: Can you write a unit test? I've no idea which data types you mean.

Comment: @npinti looks like he needs that

Comment: (Lots of "how do I parse hex in Java" questions - I chose one example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here is one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "de70d4de8c47385536c8e08348032c3b";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("..").matcher(s);

    List<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    while (m.find())
        bytes.add((byte) Integer.parseInt(m.group(), 16));

    System.out.println(bytes);
}
```

Outputs (`-34` == `0xde`):

```
[-34, 112, -44, -34, -116, 71, 56, 85, 54, -56, -32, -125, 72, 3, 44, 59]
```

Answer (score 3):

you may take a look at Apache Commons Codec [Hex.decodeHex()](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#decode%28byte%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the `String` and use `Byte.decode(String)` function to fill a byte array.

Comment: For example `"de"` is not parseable by `Byte.decode` so I don't think it would work.

Comment: You need to put "0x" as a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

unverified:

```
String md5 = "de70d4de8c47385536c8e08348032c3b";
byte[] bArray = new byte[md5.length() / 2];
for(int i = 0, k = 0; i < md5.lenth(); i += 2, k++) {
    bArray[k] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(md5[i] + md5[i+1], 16);
}
```